# Huge database indexing elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to index a database with over 1 million posts using elasticsearch the problem I'm having is that due to the amount of data the indexing crashes

is it possible to do the indexing  in parts or is this something that should not crash and I'm just doing something wrong?

I'm using Elastica (https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica)

---- edit ----

forgot to add some errors, this is what I get and after that nothing happens

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:708)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:590)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:275)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:181)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:121)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: How does it crash? Any errors? Did you verify logs?

Comment: Please add details about the "crash". Like this it could be anything from client running out of time to running out of diskspace or computer memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my error, the problem was that I was loading to much data to fast

just adding a `sleep(1);` solved the problem

Comment: The error sound like an socket timeout not catched, resulting in an incomplete http call,
anyway, hope you use Bulk indexing!

Comment: Thanks for this response, I've rebuilt my code like 3 times since this and I now have a working way of doing it, yes I use bulk but thanks for the tip =)